# Why is the button glitched on my website in visual studio code?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating my own website in visual studio code using html, css, and javascript. For some reason when I click on the Code Editors button, it loads the page for like a nano second then goes back to the home page. I have no clue what is going on and I have worked really hard on this project. Here is the code to my home page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Programmers International</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: black;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            height: 100vh; /* Adjust the height as needed */
            text-align: center;
            margin-bottom: 20px; /* Add margin to create space between containers */
        }

        h1 {
            color: white;
            margin-top: 0;
        }

        .button {
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: white;
            font-size: 20px;
            border: none;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        .button:hover {
            background-color: #45a049;
        }
    </style>
    
    <script>
      function loadPage(buttonId, pageUrl) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default button behavior
    window.location.href = pageUrl;
}

    </script>

<script>
    window.addEventListener('contextmenu', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Programmers International</h1>
        <button id="resourcesButton" class="button" onclick="loadPage('resourcesButton','Resources.html')">Resources</button>
        <button id="codeEditorsButton" class="button" onclick="loadPage('codeEditorsButton','CodeEditors.html')">Code Editors</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried every possible solution even clearing all of my browsing data including cache's, and switching to a different browser. And editing the code a million times.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. Can I ask why you're not using HTML anchors (`<a>`) for this? Buttons are not really the right thing to use for redirecting to a new page.

Comment: Code seems ok, what is in the other HTML pages? do they redirect back to your first page?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you only want to use javascript to load the page, but an easier way to would be using the hyperlink tag, you can place the pages name in their and it'll redirect.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Programmers International</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: black;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            height: 100vh; /* Adjust the height as needed */
            text-align: center;
            margin-bottom: 20px; /* Add margin to create space between containers */
        }

        h1 {
            color: white;
            margin-top: 0;
        }

        .button {
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: white;
            font-size: 20px;
            border: none;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        .button:hover {
            background-color: #45a049;
        }

        a {
            text-decoration:none;
        }
    </style>
    
    <script>
      function loadPage(buttonId, pageUrl) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default button behavior
    window.location.href = pageUrl;
}

    </script>

<script>
    window.addEventListener('contextmenu', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Programmers International</h1>
        <button id="resourcesButton" class="button" onclick="loadPage('resourcesButton','Resources.html')">Resources</button>
        <a href="" id="codeEditorsButton" class="button">Code Editors</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

So typically this isnt how I would go about writing JS with HTML. It is considered best practice to write your JS in a seperate document. Ive gone ahead and done that and I have the code for it. I used query selectors to add the event listeners instead of having the function call in the onclick attribute and it works fine for me.

to link your HTML to your JS put this at the bottom of the head element

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

the contents of the JS document that worked for me in this application are as follows.

```
codeEditorsButton = document.getElementById("codeEditorsButton");

codeEditorsButton.addEventListener(
  "onclick",
  loadPage("codeEditorsButton", "CodeEditors.html")
);
```